# How to linkTo a specific dynamic segment url in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I have a route that has a dynamic segment:

```
this.resource('dog', {path: '/dog/:pet_id'});
```

For debugging purposes, I would like to `linkTo` dog with the specific dynamic segment of '666'.  But

```
{{#linkTo 'dog' '666'}}Click to go to dog{{/linkTo}}
```

is giving me "undefined" instead of "666". Do you know why?

See [it running on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/339). 
See the [code on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/339/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Your working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/346/edit

The `linkTo` helper does not accept strings as a parameter, but instead model from which to pick up the dynamic segments defined in your router map. If you don't have a model at hand leave the parameter out, and all you need to do is to hook into the `serialize` function of your `DogRoute` *(if you don't have one defined just define it to instruct ember to use yours instead of the automatically defined)* and return an object/hash containing the dynamic segments your route expects, this could be anything you want:

```
App.DogRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serialize: function(model) {
    return {pet_id: 666};
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I cleaned up the code a little bit by removing unused bits and switching to the fixture adapter. Here's a working version without the need for a `serialize` method: http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/347

Ultimately, nothing needed to be changed in the base code beyond using a newer version of Ember and properly setting up the actual model classes and data.